# How to set permalink to other settings?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

After i migrate from one server to another, i can only set the permalink to plain setting. Whenever i try to change to other custom setting, it doesn’t work.

I always see the “ERROR 404 – PAGE NOT FOUND” message.

I am using Dokan plug-ins for multi vendor for that Product permalinks need to be set to custom base.

Please help to figure out permalink to other settings. Thank you.